# Parsing a dynamic value with Lift-JSON

Tags: json, scala, lift

Let me explain this question with an example. If I have a JSON like the following:

> {"person1":{"name": "Name One",
>   "address": {"street": "Some
>   Street","city": "Some City"}},
>   "person2":{"name": "Name Two",
>   "address": {"street": "Some Other
>   Street","city": "Some Other City"}}}

[There is no restriction on the number of persons, the input JSON can have many more persons]

I could extract this JSON to Persons object by doing

> var persons = parse(res).extract[T]

Here are the related case classes:

> case class Address(street: String,
>   city: String)
>   case class Person(name:
>   String, address: Address, children:
>   List[Child])
>   case class
>   Persons(person1: Person, person2:
>   Person)

**Question:** The above scenario works perfectly fine. However the need is that the keys are dynamic in the key/value pairs. So in the example JSON provided, *person1* and *person2* could be anything, I need to read them dynamically. What's the best possible structure for Persons class to account for that dynamic nature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to parse that is to map over child elements of the root JSON object:

```
scala> parse(res).children.map(_.extract[Person])
res3: List[Person] = List(Person(Name One,Address(Some Street,Some City)), Person(Name Two,Address(Some Other Street,Some Other City)))
```

Or like this if you need to preserve the field names:

```
scala> Map() ++ parse(res).children.map { case f: JField => (f.name, f.extract[Person]) }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Person] = Map(person1 -> Person(Name One,Address(Some Street,Some City)), person2 -> Person(Name Two,Address(Some Other Street,Some Other City)))
```

Note, the following direct way should work when we start to use 2.8 features:

```
parse(res).extract[Map[String, Person]]
```

Comment: Great! that worked like charm. BTW you did a great job with lift-json, simply superb. I would love to use Maps and Lists at the root-level, hopefully some time soon.

Comment: Thanks Surya! I'm eagerly waiting for full transition to 2.8 too. I guess we will begin to use 2.8 features after Lift 2.0 is released (the first release candidate is out soon).

Comment: Hi Joni, does lift-json do root Map objects now? I'm using lift 2.2 for Scala 2.8.1 and I don't seem to have that functionality

Comment: Hi, yes it does. You need lift 2.3 though.